# Portrait and landscape orientation on storyboards without auto-layout

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, storyboard, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm using storyboards and need to create to different views for portrait and landscape layout. I can't use auto layout in this case because I need to completely rearrange things in some cases.

I found a solution to use two different views and hide or show it depending on the device orientation but it doesn't work very good for me. I have a lot of outlets that I need to connect from xcode designer to code, and it seems that I can't connect two diffrents objects like for example two different buttons to the same IBOutlet. Can I? When I did this only one was really working. Moreover this solutions doesn't seem so efficient.

I took also a different approach and created two different view controllers which I load according to the device orientation, but there's a problem when for example I turn off application change orientation of the device and turn on it again and come back to a view controller that was in the beginning of the navigation stack, then it has an orientation that it has before.

Anyone has some ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should only use one ViewController and one view and kind of hard-code the positions of the elements. Like (pseudocode)

if (orientation landscape)
 label1.frame = ...

else (orientation portrait)
 label1.frame = ...

Maybe you can group parts of the layout within another UIView (select the elements and go in Xcode->Editor Menu->Embed->View. Then connect the new view to the ViewController and push it where you need it.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595561/alternative-ios-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-using-just-one-xib-file), maybe it helps