# Alternative iOS layouts for portrait and landscape storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, ui-design

I need to design different layouts for landscape and potrate I know how to design using .xib file but don't get how design different layout using storyboard.

I want something like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595561/alternative-ios-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-using-just-one-xib-file) but using storyboard.

please help me.

Comment: Xcode6 and the the new size classes were designed to address this issue exactly. The new Interface Builder tools are amazing and now allow you to use a singly storyboard to target all screen sizes as well as different layouts for each. I recommend watching the WWDC 2014 videos on the new Interface Builder....Short answer is you can do this with a singly storyboard now!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create different views or different constraints for each screen layout.

You can select the current screen layout here:

[image]

And you can determine whether a view is going to be present (installed) in that screen layout here (look at the bottom):

[image]

It should be clear after you play a bit with it. :)

Comment: So easy. You just create a landscape and portrait view for all your views. Thank you sir!