# How can I find out if a user has an iPhone in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I'm still confused with these changes in iOS8. I need to know if a user uses an iPhone in portrait mode. If so I want to change one constraint. Otherwise I leave it as set as in the interface builder. So how can I determine the device?

Thx!

Comment: You can define both constraints in interface builder, and iOS will switch between them accordingly. I just answered something very similar, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962222/alternative-ios-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-storyboard/25963436#25963436

Comment: That seems what I was looking for. Just one question what I don't understand yet: How can I basically take the same screen layout and ONLY change the constraint for the iPhone screens? Right now if I change it, I change it for all devices :-/

Comment: And I don't know where I can find this checkbox for which layout a view should be installed in my table view controllers :-/

Comment: You need to install the iPhone specific constraint only in the iPhone specific Screen layouts. Try selecting the different screen layout options in xcode to see what they cover.

Comment: The checkbox for a constraint is in a different place. I am adding an aswer to this question with the place screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the constraint you want to define screen layouts for:

[image]

Select the screen layouts you need your constraint installed.

[image]

Comment: Almost got it working thx alot. But If I deselect "Installed" for my one regular constraint in my Compact/Regular size layout then this constraint is also removed in the other layouts and replaced with the special constraint only for the iPhone...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to mark them installed / uninstalled exclusively per screen layout. I.e. constraint1 should be installed in CxR and not installed in RxR, while constraint2 should be installed in RxR but not in CxR

Answer (score 0):

How about this one: `UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]`
?

Comment: You probably want `[UIApplication -statusBarOrientation]`. (You want the `UIInterfaceOrientation` not the `UIDeviceOrientation`.)