# How to set Background image for all iDevice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I designed one universal application, I want to set image for all iDevice include 1x, 2x, Retina 4 2x, 3x ? How should I do? and how to set for both landscape and portrait. thank in advanced

Answer (score 1):

This naming convention will allow you to get the proper images per device:

image@2x iPhone 4/4s 
image-568h@2x iPhone 5/5s 
image-667h@2x iPhone 6 
image-736h@3x iPhone 6+

This article provides some explanation: http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/preparing-for-the-new-iphone-6-and-iphone-6-plus-screen-sizes/

In terms of changing the image per orientations / orientation change, this post seems to do a good job explaining the necessary calls.

[Alternative iOS layouts for portrait and landscape using just one .xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595561/alternative-ios-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-using-just-one-xib-file)

Comment: You know this question's about native app development, not a web page, right?